# I want my button to Change it value to the currency I select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want is when I select "AUD" from the dropdown menu my button's("dropbtn") innerHtml changes to "AUD" similarly other way around. I want my button to change its text to the text of the  I select from my dropdown menu
Here is the code:
App.js:

```
    import './App.css'
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [listopen, setListopen] = useState(false)
  const Dropdown = () => {
    if (listopen) {
      setListopen(false)

    } else {
      setListopen(true)

    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <li><button class="dropbtn" onClick={() => Dropdown()}  >USD

            </button></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown" style={{ display: listopen === false ? 'none' : 'block' }}>
              <a href="/">AUD($)</a>
              <a href="/">USD($)</a>
              <a href="/">PKR($)</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>

      </nav>
    </main>
  )
}
```

App.css:

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1a2456;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 100;
    width: 9.5vw;

  }
 .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: #fead94;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 100;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a state for the text on the button and have a click event on the dropdrown

```
export default function App() {
  const [listopen, setListopen] = useState(false)
  const [btnText, setBtnText] = useState("Default Text");
  
  const Dropdown = () => { 
    setListopen(!listopen) //Same functionality as yours but less code
  }

  const handleOptionClick = (txt)=> {
    setBtnText(txt);
  }


  return (
    <main>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <li><button class="dropbtn" onClick={() => Dropdown()}> {btnText}

            </button></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown" style={{ display: listopen === false ? 'none' : 'block' }}>
              <a href="/" onClick={()=> handleOptionClick("AUD")}>AUD($)</a>
              <a href="/" onClick={()=> handleOptionClick("USD")}>USD($)</a>
              <a href="/"onClick={()=> handleOptionClick("PKR")}>PKR($)</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>

      </nav>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Also you can modify DropDown function for less code like I did

Comment: Thanks the code works and you have solved my problem but what if there are many options, is there a way we dont have to set all the value manually in on click function it automatically takes the value from innerHtml

Comment: I'm glad that helped. The most correct implementation to this is similar to the one devCecy put. Where you put it in the Id and take the value from the handleEvent event object. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events#passing-event-handlers-as-props

Answer (score 0):

1. using your code

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [listopen, setListopen] = useState(false);
  const Dropdown = () => {
    if (listopen) {
      setListopen(false);
    } else {
      setListopen(true);
    }
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState("USD");
  const handleChangeValue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValue(e.target.id);
  };
  return (
    <main>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <li>
              <button className="dropbtn" onClick={() => Dropdown()}>
                {value}
              </button>
            </li>
            <div
              class="dropdown-content"
              id="myDropdown"
              style={{ display: listopen === false ? "none" : "block" }}
            >
              <a href="/" id="AUD" onClick={handleChangeValue}>
                AUD($)
              </a>
              <a href="/" id="USD" onClick={handleChangeValue}>
                USD($)
              </a>
              <a href="/" id="PKR" onClick={handleChangeValue}>
                PKR($)
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </main>
  );
}
```

2. using select tag

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("AUD");
  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>{selectedValue}</p>
      <select id="select" onChange={handleSelectChange}>
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
        <option value="PKR">PKR</option>
      </select>
    </>
  );
}
```

hope it was helpful to you!